# HP Fortify UI customization

Tags: eclipse, customization, development-environment, fortify

It's possible to modify Fortify Eclipse color schema?

I have found some files at this path

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Fortify\workspace\
```

that looks like the one used by Eclipse to define the color of the code but can't come with a way to successful modify them.

**UPDATE:** Fortify version is "Audit Workbench 3.50". It uses Eclipse code editor to display code but it isn't a Eclipse plug-in. I have discovered that they use the same files Eclipse does to customize look and feel but didn't manage to modify them successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you press Ctrl+Shift+L twice (where Ctrl=Cmd for Mac), a preferences dialog appears that allows some changes to the Eclipse UI properties in the Audit Workbench perspective.

- For Java projects, go to Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring on
  the left and select how java keywords are highlighted selecting
  Element: Java -> Keywords excluding 'return'
- There's similar preference for C++ projects under C/C++ ->
  Editor -> Syntax Coloring.
- Some colors can be set on Java (or C/C++) -> Editor page itself (like
  matching brackets highlight color). Note, it uses the simplified
  java editor, so complicated things like static fields and some others
  will not work.
- To set current line highlight color, go to General ->
  Editors -> Text Editors and select 'Current line highlight' color.
- Go to General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts, to play with other
  elements' look and feel.

Not all of the color preferences in that dialog will work because there are some hard-coded backgrounds in some of the widgets.

As always, Your Mileage May Vary!

Comment: I don't currently have access to Fortify but I'll check next time and, if it works, I'll mark your answer as the right one, but looking good as it works on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse is it?  Is the Fortify software a plugin of some type in Eclipse?

I've never used the HP Fortify software before, but I'll start with the obvious to change text appearance in eclipse:  Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Wiki Text -> Appearance.

I'm taking a guess that there may be some similar options under a plugin if it got added to Eclipse.